# Interpolating flood surface using Topo to Raster in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, interpolation, error-010067, anudem

I am trying to interpolate a statewide flood surface for NJ using Topo to Raster in ArcPy. I split the input points into 900 separate input point feature classes using 14-digit watershed boundaries. I am also using these boundaries as the processing extent, output extent, and mask for each output surface. Runing the code with an output cell size of 10 gives me the following **error**:

---

ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [4]:
Line 28:    TTRout = TopoToRaster(TopoPointElevation([[point,"grid_code"]]), cell_size="10",

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py, in TopoToRaster:
Line 17955: return Wrapper(

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py, in swapper:
Line 55:    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py, in Wrapper:
Line 17930: result = arcpy.gp.TopoToRaster_sa(

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py, in :
Line 520:   return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))

ExecuteError: ERROR 010235: Returned error from Topo_To_Raster.
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (TopoToRaster).

**Here is my code**:

```
#paths
infeatws = r"Data\HUC14pt100b"
inextws = r"Data\HUC14shp100b"
outputpath = r"HUC14TTR.gdb"

#set environment workspace for point files (HUC14_pt_100)
env.workspace = infeatws

#create list of point feature classes with paths
infeatures = [os.path.join(infeatws, feature) for feature in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()]
print(infeatures)

#set environment workspace for extent/mask files (HUC14_shp_100)
env.workspace = inextws

#create list of extent polygon feature classes with paths
inextents = [os.path.join(inextws, extent) for extent in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()]
print(inextents)

#iterate through input point feature classes and extent polygon feature classes
for i, (point, poly) in enumerate(zip(infeatures, inextents)):
    print(i, point, poly)
    #set processing extent
    arcpy.env.extent = poly
    #set mask
    arcpy.env.mask = poly
    #Topo to Raster
    TTRout = TopoToRaster(TopoPointElevation([[point,"grid_code"]]), cell_size="10", 
                       extent=poly, enforce="ENFORCE", data_type="SPOT")
    print(TTR)
    #save 
    TTRout.save(f"{output_path}\HUC14TTR{i}")
```

When I increase the ouput cell size to 100, the code runs without the error, so the problem must be the cell size. I can run the tool in ArcGIS Pro with an output cell size of 10 without a problem.

Is there a way to do it in ArcPy?

Comment: Why not use the FEMA flood data?  https://www.fema.gov/flood-maps

Comment: Unless you are obfuscating your code (not much help to us) it might be down to your workspace `infeatws = r"Data\HUC14pt100b"` is not a proper full path to a  geodatabase.

Comment: I suggest using poly.extent when defining arcpy.env.extent or use describe first to get extent of polygonal feature class